# Axis specific subgrid devision using \psgrid

Tags: pstricks

If I want to devide a grid into subgrids using PSTricks, I use the command `\psgrid` with the option `subgriddiv=<integer>`. This, however, sets the number of subgrids to the same on both axis; is it possible to get a different subdivision for each axis?

Comment: use `\psaxes` instead of `\psgrid`

Comment: @Herbert Can you maybe give an example? It is probably something trivial but I cannot figure out how to use `\psaxes` to get what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,7)
\psaxes[xsubticks=5, xticksize=0 7, xsubticksize=1,
        ysubticks=2, yticksize=0 5, ysubticksize=1,
        subtickcolor=black!30](5,7)
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't knew of those options at all. Great, Herbert!

Comment: How do I set the linestyle for the grid and subgrid? I cannot find anything in the `pstricks-add` manual.

Comment: Specifically, I would like to make the grid and subgrid lines dotted.

Comment: there are _a lot_ of examples in the documentation.

Comment: I cannot find any examples of this, unfortunately. (Can you give a page numbers or something?) I have tried to envoke `\psaxes[...,linestyle=dotted,...](x,y)` but then the axes themselves become dotted and the grid disappears.

Comment: There is _no_ example in pst-plot-doc which uses `linestyle=dotted` ... The examples for subticklines are pp 46, 48, 49, 69, and Table 1 lists _all_ optional arguments with a page reference. And on http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/psaxes is also an example for dashed lines.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't say that there were any examples with that; it was just my try because I couldn't figure out the right way to do it. `:-)` (Now I see the problem; I looked in `pstricks-add-doc`.)