# Grid and tick marks in the same PSTricks picture

Tags: pstricks, grids, pst-plot, ticks

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{
  xunit = 0.05,
  yunit = 0.003,
  algebraic
}
\begin{pspicture}(-17,-140)(213,2540)
  % Axes
  \psaxes[
    dx = 20,
    dy = 250,
    labels = none,
    ticklinestyle = dotted,
    tickwidth = 0.5pt,
    xticksize = 0 2250,
    yticksize = 0 200
  ]{->}(0,0)(-4,-60)(210,2400)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psaxes[
    dx = 20,
    Dx = 20,
    dy = 250,
    Dy = 250
  ](0,0)(-4,-60)(210,2400)
  % Functions.
  \psplot[linecolor = red]{0}{200}{1.75*x+500}
  \rput(190,700){$y$}
  \psplot[linecolor = blue]{0}{200}{10*x}
  \rput(190,2030){$z$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

What is the 'correct'/'best' way to add both a grid with dotted lines and solid tick marks to a graph using [`pst-plot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot)? As can be seen in the example above, I have done it by drawing two coordinate systems, but is there a simpler way of getting the same?

Comment: You could use `\psgrid`, bit AFAIKS that would bring you [back to where you started from](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131049/33933). But as there are now different options to generate tics and grid, I can't see a 'better' way.

Comment: Okay, thank you. (Indeed, it would be going back to start (and not using an advice from @Herbert on PSTricks).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{\psset{xunit=20,yunit=250}       
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt](0,0)(10,9)%     
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand this. When should I use `\psgrid` and when not?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Depends `;)`. The `\psgrid` will have different dot spacing in `x` and `y`-direction because you have different units. The `\psaxes` has equals dot spacing in both directions.

Comment: @Christoph Okay. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: You asked for an _alternative_ to `\psaxes`. There is no "best way". It depends to your axes